# Port forward not working from modem to router to server

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

Here is my environment:

WAN Cable -> Docsis 3 Zoom 1094 Modem -> TP-Link AC1750 Dual Link Router -> Server to forward

(dynamic public IP) -> Modem: (internal nic: `192.168.100.1`) -> Router: `10.1.1.1` -> Internal Server (`10.1.1.10`)

I turned off the firewall to Internal Server for now to make sure *everything* can get in/out. It is also set to have a static IP

In the 'Router' `10.1.1.1`. management interface I went to Forwarding -> Virtual Servers and added an allow to `10.1.1.10` on port 80 TCP/UDP and enabled it

I change the router management interface to 8080 so there is no port 80 conflict just because.

Docsis 3 Zoom 1094 modem has no configurable options, just an info page at `192.168.100.1`, this is accessible from all PCs on the network.

When I attempt to access my public IP—as listed in the router and on whatsmyip.com—I get a error that no data was received. Internally, when accessing the IP the web server responds.

Strangely, when I enter my public IP on a PC in my internal network it still lands on the internal server page I am trying to access.

I can not figure out what configurations are wrong. UPNP is on, DMZ computer is off, no port triggering rules. More info below

Here is the cable modem info page: (from 192.168.100.1)
[image]

Here is some IP and router info:

[image]

Here is the LAN info:
[image]

WAN info from router:
[image]

NAT Settings:
[image]

Port forward settings:
[image]

Comment: Added a lot of info. There's a DMZ setting which I tried setting the server to but that also didn't seem to work? ;(

Comment: http://www.cox.com/residential/support/internet/article.cox?articleId=cacf82f0-6407-11df-ccef-000000000000  Inbound port 80 is blocked by Cox.

Comment: Welp, that was dumb. ;(

Is there any way to get around this so that I can point to domainame.com (on port 80) and have that go to dynamicip.com:port## so that it is easy for the user to access but still avoids the port 80 block? Is this something cloudflare coud do?

Comment: I haven't used cloudflare, but if they can proxy your site on a different port, say 8080, instead of 80, then that should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to Cox blocking port 80. Currently this is not resolved, I am looking in to proxying (perhaps through cloudflare) sitename.com on port 80 to public-ip:otherport so that this inconvenience isn't visible to people accessing the site.

Comment: Port 80 blocking is to prevent a residential connection from runnibg a webserver.  You can upgrade to a business connection and that'll let you host on port 80.

Comment: Since this will hardly have any load (maybe 5 max connections?) and minimal traffic I don't want to spend the money on a business account esp after dealing with 2 bad router/modems they sent me initially and a botched initial setup. I also don't need the static  =/

Comment: Then you can setup the connection on a custom port since it looks like the connections are people you know.